# Wordpress dropdown menu values not in running order

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a dropdown menu (select number of pax) which consists of the 'tags' I added in the backend. The are basically integers like 2,3-4,5-6,7-8 etc. Everything looks fine and in order until I begin adding the tag '13,15' - this value actually appeared on the top of the list. I figured it's because WordPress detects the first digit to be '1' and according to my PHP code, the 'order' is set to 'ASC'.

Is there a way to make it still in running order and let WordPress detect it as the number '13' instead of just looking at the first digit?

My dropdown menu looks like this right now:

13-15
2
3-4
5-6
7-8
9-10

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe looking for something natsort. Try and use that on your tag array, http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

It's difficult to see without code. Maybe you are talking about your SQL query, in that case there is a good post about it here: http://www.copterlabs.com/natural-sorting-in-mysql/